# Javascript/JQuery - How to get number of specific child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to get the number of all TR elements that have a input element in them somewhere. How should I proceed ?

Html :

`<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Ignore this item 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ignore this item 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input blablabla>... Include this TR...</td>
</tr>
</tbody>`

Thanks!

Comment: WHat do you mean, "get the number"?  Do you mean that you want to count them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('tr:has(input)').length`